# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Tags: resources, ioexception

Application is unable to load ANY xaml. Nor create empty window "var abc = new Window1();"

Error message is still the same:

An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot locate resource 'wvmlog.xaml'. (for wvmlog.xaml)
Exception occur on InitializeComponent();

These objects are created without error on another PC - so problem is not in Project settings.

Do not help:

- reinstall VS
- new install of VS
- reinstal .net frameworks
- undo source from TFS
- complete new workspace and load from TFS
- visual studio Clean colution
- find and delete all cached dll, pbd
- remove all obj directories in solution
- install and use VS 2010, VS 2012, VS 2013
- move VS and solution into another hard drive

Do Help:

- Copy of project (help for 1-2 days, then problem appear again without any manipulation with xaml)
- Change solution configuration from 'Debug' to 'Release' (help for 1-2 days, then problem appear in Release configuration without any manipulation with xaml)

Problem is at one PC with Win 7, 64-bit.
The problem occur suddenly after some xaml window renaming, but these changes was many times undo-ed, but problem remain.

Maybe some OS damage, or some wpf/.net caches?

Why wpf/.net show such error on project which is compiled without error - so compiler KNOW that these resources does exist?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This problem continue on one PC even after reinstall an change OS to Win 8. After change of xaml, application load it and show some cached version from somwhere. The PC has i7 processor with 8 cores, 8 gb ram, SSD disk, 64 bit. Wpf somewhere cache xaml (baml) / dll.

Comment: Helped me VisualStudioCleaner from CodeProject. It seems the problem is in some of garbage in solution directory (not in OS, not in GAC, not in VS installation)

Comment: Hi, did you do anything else? We have the same problem over here, but the cleaner is not able to get it going again

Answer (score 17):

I had this very same issue. 
What design pattern are you using?

The issue I had was when I changed the output window ie created a new one and deleted the old one.

I am using MVVM so I created the window in the View folder.

If this is your issue, your APP.XAML will look like:

```
<Application x:Class="dotDiff2013.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

You then change the startURI to wherever your new window is stored. ie in the view folder.

```
StartupUri="Main/MainWindow.xaml"
```

This helped for me. Hope it's the solver to your problem.